# Pandas: How to loop through each character of a long string, perform addition if the character meets certain type and numerical criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some 35-character-long strings that include a combination of integers and dashes. They look like this:

- `23344--33344--43344--53344--63344--`
- `466554-566554-666554-666554-666554-`

How can I perform a logical comparison by looping through each element of that long string?

Specifically, I would like to loop through the entire 35-character-long string, and add 2 to an integer if that integer is less than 4. No addition is needed if it is a "-".

(Note that in the actual data, all integer digits are between 1 and 6, so adding 2 would not make any of the digits into double-digits.)

Here's some code I wrote:

```
let A = '23344--33344--43344--53344--63344--'
  for i in range(0,35):
    if A[i] != '-':  
      if A[i].astype(Int) < 4:
        A[i] = A[i] + 2
```

But it returns the error `'str' object has no attribute 'astype'` .

Additionally, I am not even sure if the looping above is an efficient way to calculate this. As in my real data, I have a table that contains ~1 million rows, and those 35-character-long strings is one of the column of that table.

Comment: What happens in the case that a digit be 8 or 9?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for your reply! in the actual data, all integer digits are between 1 and 6, so adding 2 would not make any of the digits into double-digit. I modified the examples I gave above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `str.replace` with a callback function:

```py
df["col"] = df["col"].str.replace(r'[0-3]', lambda m: str(int(m.group()) + 2))
```

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, is there a way to add logic in str.replace? (e.g. instead of "if that integer is less than 4", the logic is "if that integer add 2 is less than 4"). Understand this is an extra logic from the original ask, so happy to ask a new question if needed.

Comment: @Patrick The logic `if that integer add 2 is less than 4` would seem to imply that you only want to add 2 if the digit be 0 or 1 (thus resulting in 2 and 3, respectively).  If so, then just do an `re.sub` on `[01]`